# How to find all the places in the org where a particular record type is used?

Tags: record-type

On the Task object, I have 4 RTs. I want to know at which places a particular record type has been used like Apex Classes, Process Builders,etc.
Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: You may need to use IDE to search for this. As there is no exact way to know because you can there might be a scenario where record type developers have been named in Labels and referenced in code. This is mostly a manual search.

Comment: Does this answer your query https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/228623/check-all-dependencies-of-a-record-type-in-the-organisation-before-deactivating

Comment: For now I am going with the IDE method as mentioned bby @NagendraSingh...thanks for such quick responses!

Comment: @NagendraSingh seems like you should post your comment as an answer.

Comment: Done, posted as an answer @PhilW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to use IDE to search for this. As there is no exact way to know because there might be a scenario where record type developers have been named in Labels and referenced in code. This is mostly a manual search.